# danielgindi/charts: How get round corners for Graph?

Tags: ios-charts

I am using iOS Charts (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) for line chart.

I gave background color to grid (Light Gray) as don’t want to include axis values.

[image]

lineChartView.gridBackgroundColor = .lightGray

Is there any way i can make corner of the graph rounded. not able to give corner radius for grid background color.

Comment: You can corner radius by setting radius to that layer . For ex: [graylayerobj.layer setCornerRadius:30.0f];

Comment: @ScorpianAlive tried that.. didnt work